# How to print the jasper report on console

Tags: jasper-reports

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("IMAGES_MAP", imagesMap);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_MAP, imagesMap);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "" + request.getContextPath() + "//image?image=");

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outStream);
```

After this I set the out to a iframe and it works fine.

Before sending the exported html page I want the html page to be printed in console because when the same report is viewed in pdf the colors come but the colors do not come in html format.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to output to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperExportManager.html#exportReportToHtmlFile%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint,%20java.lang.String%29) method allows you to export the html to a file and you may use the [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) `readFileToString(new File(destinationHtmlFile))` to get the contents of the file as a string which you may print on the console